# 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' using keras_core and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I scratch my head on the following (simplistic) problem using keras_core on tensorflow

```py
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"

import numpy as np
import keras_core as keras
import tensorflow as tf
import torch

print("Keras version: ", keras.__version__)
print("numpy version: ", np.__version__)
print("tensorflow version: ", tf.__version__)
print("torch version: ", torch.__version__)

d_input = 12
d_output = 5

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(int(d_input),))
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(
    int(d_output), use_bias=False, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
loss_function = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
metrics = [keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=metrics)

batch_size = 24

X = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(2*batch_size, d_input))
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(2*batch_size, d_output))
X = keras.ops.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype="int8")
y = keras.ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype="int8")

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size)
```

that returns

```py
Using TensorFlow backend

2023-11-07 15:32:41.037477: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

2023-11-07 15:32:42.714479: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-11-07 15:32:42.716272: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.

Keras version:  0.1.7
numpy version:  1.23.5
tensorflow version:  2.10.0
torch version:  2.0.1

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "~/script.py", line 34, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size)

  File "~miniconda3/envs/nn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_core/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "~miniconda3/envs/nn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras_core/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 69, in train_step
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_weights)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'
```

that I do not understand. Note I'm using the new [keras_core](https://keras.io/keras_core/) package. I did not try with jax.

Replacing tensorflow by torch do not raise any error: `os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "torch"`. Versions are on the output above.

Any help is warm welcome, either to improve the question or help finding an anwser :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the following line

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(int(d_input),))
```

to

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(int(d_input),))
```

Comment: Thank you @coderina ! Could you please give more details ?